# como exibir mais de um projeto no explorer do Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Galera,

Uma dúvida, comecei a utilizar o virtual studio code para testes, anteriormente utilizada o sublime, e o que estou sentindo falta e não consegui fazer foi, fazer com que ele aceite eu ter mais de um projeto aberto no explorer, ou seja, tenho dois projetos em pastas diferentes queria que ambos ficassem listados no explorer do visual studio code.

Ou seja, ele não tem a opção "adicionar pastas ao projeto" igual tem no sublime, ai cada vez que preciso ver algo em um projeto e mando abrir uma pasta ele fecha o projeto atual e abre outra janela com a nova pasta.

Alguem saberia me dizer se tem como? Desde já agradeço,

Comment: Criei um workspace e adicionei vários pastas. Parece que isso resolve o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é alvo de debate à algum tempo e é um recurso ainda não disponível no momento.

Em resumo, a comunidade está trabalhando na inclusão desta funcionalidade. O Roadmap definido para Setembro/2017, visa principalmente tornar a transição entre o modelo um único diretório root para múltiplos suave, evitando problemas com extensões e funcionalidades já existentes. Provavelmente, veremos esta funcionalidade até o fim deste ano (2017).

Veja [este link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/396) para a discussão da proposta de inclusão deste recurso e [este](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28344) para o Roadmap para desenvolvimento do feature.

Comment: Vlw...muito obrigado vou acompanhar o forum..cheguei a procurar mais não tinha encontrado nada relacionado ao assunto.

Comment: Miguel, podes colocar aqui algum conteúdo traduzido desse link? Se o link deixar de funcionar a tua resposta fica inutilizada.

Comment: Certamente Sérgio, realmente a resposta estava inadequada e a situação alterou-se deste então.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais prática é abrir uma nova janela File->New Window e deixá-las lado a lado.

Answer (score -1):

É apenas adicionar pasta ao seu Workspace:

Clique em `Arquivo` > `Adicionar Pasta ao Workspace`. Uma janela irá abir, para você escolher a pasta que quer abrir com as outras.

[image: Imagem mostrando aonde que fica o botão]